# form a function name from string MATLAB

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation

I am trying to a call a function using the following code:
 {

```
   fileName = strsplit(file,'.');
   Process = strcat(fileName(1),'_config()')
```

}

The code works if I hard code: Process = EDA_config() but when I use the above to concatenate the string where fileName(1) = 'EDA', it results in an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For thet purpose use `eval`, but be **sure** you **need** to do it. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding me. I had used eval to do the same many months ago, just couldn't recall. It worked right away. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Actually I hurried to answer, it is not working I get the following error: Undefined function 'eval' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: `eval` needs a `string` type, so `eval([varName{2},'=1'])` will assign 1 to `Foo` variable, where `varName={'Bar';'Foo';'BarFoo'};`

Comment: but once again, if you can avoid `eval`, **do** avoid `eval`.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, for my purpose, using 'char' fixed the issue.

Comment: I'd like once to see all the "eval is evil" guys (including me!) wrestling every person ever implemented this feature in some programming language.

Comment: Also, in MATLAB, simple string concatenation is the same as array concatenation: `['asfg', 'asgsa']` will concatenate the two.